# Unable to free up any space

Tags: iphone

I am literally unable to free up any space on my iPhone 5S (iOS 10.1.1). I delete apps and photos and emails (when I have enough space to use mail), but it stays saying I have 0KB available. Even if I do delete an app or even 300+ (in one instance) photos, I STILL somehow manage to have no free space. Even if it does free space, it's often not a lot of space and it often runs out very quickly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've also tried turning my phone on and off again. Doesn't do anything either

Comment: Delete photos get moved to trash for 30 days, did you delete them from there as well? Also, can you please add a screenshot of "Settings -> General -> Memory/iCloud Usage -> Manage Memory"?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend backing up your phone using iTunes and then restore using the last backup. This should help in freeing up space, mostly if you do OTA upgrades.